# How to take an OS level screen capture using ruby selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I know selenium has an option to take a screen capture of a webpage
using

```
@driver.save_screenshot("image.png")
```

but is there a function to take an OS level screen capture?
with the browser header, background etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do this without using selenium.  Selenium/Webdriver really only interacts with the browser.  It's not meant to perform OS level functions.

I'm not a ruby user, but I found this with a quick Google search:https://github.com/jarmo/win32screenshot If you are on windows, this seems like it might work.

Comment: I do agree that selenium is primarily for automating web applications for testing purposes, but its not limited to just that. Infact Selenium RC 1 infact had an OS level screen capture with `$sel->capture_screenshot($location.'image.png');` as a command in perl. I was actually looking for something like that. nonethe less thanks for ur response.